# Better performance on DateOffset and BDay?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, time-series

I am trying to do a simple operation:

1. Get the date of one month ago
2. If the result is not business day, then take next business day.

using code:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset, BDay
from datetime import datetime

def last_month(d):
    start = time.time()
    last = d - DateOffset(months=1) + BDay(0)
    end = time.time()
    print (end - start)

now = datetime.now()
last_month(now)
```

I get the time printed as `0.000224113464355`

I think for my requirement it is too slow. I have about `100K` dates that I need to do similar operation like above `last_month`, then the total cost will be `0.000224113464355 * 100, 000` about **22 seconds**.

Is there any better way in *python* or *pandas* to achieve this faster?

Comment: Doesn't it just work if you just did `df['date_col'] - DateOffset(months=1) + BDay(0)`?

Comment: I get `10 loops, best of 3: 72.4 ms per loop` for 100K rows

Comment: @EdChum I can't do it because I am not transforming the date index of the df. Instead, for each date,  I need to find data of 12 business days from 12 months, which means say for `2016-2-2`, i need to find `2016-01-02`, `2015-12-02`, etc, if not weekday, then find the nearest bday.